# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined unable to fix it

Tags: reactjs, axios, web-deployment

```
 axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
      .then(response => {
        if (response !== undefined  && response.data.statewise.length>0) {
          self.setState({ data: response.data.statewise }, () => {
            self.getTestingData()
          })
        }
    })
```

When I am deploying the app on heroku, page doesn't gets loaded (https://asciiclan-covid19.herokuapp.com/)

It is showing cannot read length of undefined and refering to above code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
import React , {useEffect, useState}from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const Covid = () => {
    const [states, setStates] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        
        Axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json').then(res => {
            if (res !== undefined  && res.data.statewise.length>0) {

               
                setStates(res.data.statewise );
            } 
        }    
        );
    } , []);

   const state = states.map((item, index) => {
       
       return(

           <p key = {index}>{item.state}</p>
       );
})

    return (
        <div>
            {state}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Covid
```